# Selected item changes after sort

Tags: python, django

I am making Django app and i have a quesiton i have made a select menu to sort by prices. When I click submit button it sorts but it also refresh page and go back to the default selected item.

views.py

```
def sortView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            min_price = int(request.GET.get('min-price'))  
            max_price = int(request.GET.get('max-price')) 
            items = Item.objects.filter(Q(price__gte=min_price) & Q(price__lte=max_price))
        except:
            sorting_method = request.GET.get('select')
            if sorting_method == 'v1':
                items = Item.objects.order_by('price')
            elif sorting_method == 'v2':
                items = Item.objects.order_by('-price')
            print(sorting_method)

    return render(request, 'shop/sort.html', {'items': items})
```

HTML: It is in a 'form' so it is not the issue.

```
<label class="sort__dropdown" for="cars">Sorting method</label>
            <select name="select">
                <option value="v1">Price: low to high</option>
                <option value="v2">Price: high to low</option>
            </select>
         <button class="sort__submit">SORT</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are setting the "currently selected" item when you send the sorted result.  The browser can't rememberthat.  You might consider handling the sort in Javascript, instead of making a round trip.  It's a bit more work, but a better experience.

Comment: It might be a good idea to check django filter package https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#ordering-filter that provides great functionality when it comes to sorting/filtering and rendering the form.